# Error while creating react app on the wordpress CMS

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

While creating the react app on the WordPress CMS I got the "create-react-wptheme not found" error. How can I fix this issue? I tried this code to install create-react-wptheme on server.

```
1. npm i -g create-react-wptheme
2. npm i create-react-wptheme
3. npm install create-react-wptheme
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You only need 2 steps:

1. npm i -g create-react-wptheme
2. create-react-wptheme myproject

Comment: It works but only created a empty folder